# Programmatically make the volume full from mute

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am working on iphone app. I want to tap a button for playing an .wav file. then I want to check if the volume of iphone is mute then make it louder and play the .wav file. Is it possible programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this....
http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-play-audio-with-the-iphone-sdk

this link for audio play..
when you are able to play sound,then for mute the sound just write `soundname.volume = 0;`and when you want to up the volume then just write `soundname.volume=5`

Answer (score 1):

I believe not. iOS only allows the "user" to change settings like these.

Even if it was possible, I would highly doubt if it would pass the App Store terms of publication.

Comment: can we make iphone from silent mode to vibration mode or general mode

Comment: @NajeebullahShah: Nup.. you can not

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check the volume by,

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] volume];
```

set the volume by,

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] setVolume: value];
```